# Who was the lady mending the toy at the end?

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, the-boy-2016

I started watching the movie *The Boy* (2016). I noticed that at the ending of the movie someone is again mending the toy named Brahms. The toy boy (Brahms) was broken and there is no one in the house to repair him. His parents were dead and the hand of the lady who was mending the boy was his mother's.

How was this possible when she died in water in the movie? How can she be come back and how can he have been repaired by her mother? Isn't she died or this is anything else?

Answer (score 0):

The end of the movie, we go back to the mansion to find “someone” was gluing the porcelain Brahms’ face back together. That person should be Brahms:
He is in Brahms' secret room, inside the walls.
He was wearing Brahms’ sweater.

[image: Brahms’ sweater][image: Brahms' secret room]

> The film then ends with a hand rebuilding the doll, implying that
>   Brahms is still alive.

[wikia](http://villains.wikia.com/wiki/Brahms_Heelshire)

> Later, Brahms, who has survived, is seen repairing the shattered doll.

[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Boy_(2016_film))